# Parameter in the url?

Tags: html, sql, coldfusion

I have a page with two different links: Active and InActive employee (shown below). Click the first link to view Active employees, and the second link to view In-active employees.

I want to add a parameter to the URL for these links. I want to send "Active" with the link of active employees and "In-active" with the link of inactive employees. After that if URL parameter is active I want to query only those who are active or if its inactive to query only inactive employee. Here I have two pages created for my employees:

```
<li><a href="ActiveEmployee.cfm">Active Employee</a></li>

<li><a href="InActiveEmployee.cfm">InActive Employee</a></li>
```

and here is my query:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Age, Active
From Employees
Where Active Like '%Active%'
```

I'm not sure if this can be done this way. I still did not get my code to work properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need two separate pages for this. Just use one page, and let the page use the url parameter to decide what to show. If you're going to use two pages, the url parameter is redundant and meaningless.

Comment: Also: show the coldfusion mark-up surrounding your query, to give us context for how to integrate the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joel pointed out you should have one page. Your links would look like

```
<a href="Employee.cfm?isActive=1">Active Employee</a>
<a href="Employee.cfm?isActive=0">InActive Employee</a>
```

At the top of your Employee.cfm you may want to default this parameter

```
<cfparam name="url.isActive" type="numeric" default="1">
```

You should also use cfqueryparam in your query

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="#myDSN#">
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age, Active
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Active = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.isActive#">
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do this on the same page.

You'd want the URL to be something like `Employees.cfm?status=Active` or `status=Inactive`

Then the query:

```
<cfif isDefined("URL.status")>
<cfquery name="poo" datasource="whatever">
SELECT Employee
FROM EmployeeTable
WHERE Active LIKE '#URL.status#'
</cfquery>
</cfif>
```

You may also want to use a cfqueryparam when you're taking variables from a URL or Form. It helps prevent SQL injection.

If you don't want to change the way you're doing it (though you could and should) you can just dump the CGI scope to get the query string or template path, and write a conditional query off that. (If template path contains inactiveemployee.cfm, execute this query).

Comment: You should NEVER trust input form user's. The query should be parameterized, otherwise, it is open to SQL injection.

Comment: If you had read the answer you'd have found that I stated as much.

Comment: Why not use `cfqueryparam` in the code, the way Boszlo did? Odds are OP will simply copy/paste your code..and if it works, go merrily about their way and be none the wiser.

Comment: I don't know what datatype his column for "active" will wind up being and I'd rather not guess. If he doesn't read and understand my very clear comment, that's not my problem, and StackOverflow isn't for making copypasta out of work you don't understand.

Comment: To me, the better way would have been to put the `cfqueryparam` in the code and then say you may need to adjust the SQL type. Your comment made it seem as if it was OK to not use `cfqueryparam`, when, in reality, it is not. I thought StackOverflow was to help people become better developers.

Comment: Your code already assumes a data type, so adding `cfqueryparam` to your answer would not have made any additional assumptions.

Comment: I don't like that the query only conditionally exists